# How to fix "'BROWSER' is not recognized as an internal or external command"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I am trying to run react-d3-tree-demo following this README.md at https://github.com/bkrem/react-d3-tree-demo

After following the other steps, I got stuck on the second step of trying to run the app locally. The command line returns an error: "'BROWSER' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file," when I try to execute "npm run dev" in the react-d3-tree-demo directory that I cloned from the same repo.

The README.md page instructs to run "npm run dev" in both the react-d3-tree and react-d3-tree-demo directories. I actually got an error when I did that command in the react-d3-tree directory where the command line said the linebreak was incorrect, but I went into the eslintrc.js file and added "'linebreak-style': 0," in the module exports which resolved the error. I've tried turning off my Avast antivirus software which was suggested on another page. Nothing has worked so far.

To reproduce my problem:

Demo:
Clone this repo: git clone https://github.com/bkrem/react-d3-tree-demo.git
cd react-d3-tree-demo
Run yarn or npm install OR run bash ./setup.sh and skip to Running locally

React-D3-Tree library:
Inside the react-d3-tree-demo directory, clone the library: git clone https://github.com/bkrem/react-d3-tree.git
Run yarn or npm install

Running locally:
Set up 2 terminal windows, one in the react-d3-tree-demo directory, the other in react-d3-tree-demo/react-d3-tree (i.e. the sub-directory into which we cloned the library itself)
Run yarn dev/npm run dev in each
Any changes made to the demo app or the library should now automatically rebuild the library and reload the app with the fresh build (via nodemon).

I expect the react app to open a page at localhost:8000 that looks like this: https://bkrem.github.io/react-d3-tree-demo/ however, I get a message from the command line that was detailed earlier. I'm not sure why they told me to clone react-d3-tree inside the demo, I'd appreciate any explanation of that also.

Comment: Works fine for me. You'd run that in the demo directory--what OS are you using? All it's doing is setting an environment variable (`BROWSER`).

Comment: Interesting. I am using Windows. I was able to fix my problem somehow in the manner I described below.

Answer (score 22):

Do an npm install of cross-env in your cloned repo: 
`npm install --save cross-env`

Then in your cloned repo, open up package.json and change dev to this:

`"dev": "cross-env BROWSER=none yarn clean:lib && webpack --progress --colors --watch --env dev",`

Basically adding this to the beginning of the command: `cross-env BROWSER=none`

BROWSER is an environment variable, and you can use the cross-env package to properly handle it.

Now try running `npm run dev` again, and it should work.

Comment: I actually was able to just fix it by removing BROWSER=none from the package.json file. I'm not sure what that did, but when I tried npm run dev again, it opened up properly. I appreciate your advice!

Comment: Removing `BROWSER=none` worked for me too!

Answer (score 16):

There are two fixes I found that work perfectly well

1. Install cross-env (npm package [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env)) npm install cross-env then you change your dev script to

   > `"electron-dev": "concurrently \"cross-env BROWSER=none yarn start\" \"wait-on http://localhost:3000 && electron .\""`,
2. Install concurrently and run this (on windows though)

   > `"electron-dev": "concurrently \"SET BROWSER=none&&npm run start\" \"wait-on http://localhost:3000 && electron .\""`

please note that you also have to install concurrently if not already installed

Answer (score 8):

i success using cross-env,  so try this one:

"dev": "concurrently -k "cross-env BROWSER=none npm start" "npm:electron"",
"electron": "wait-on http://localhost:3000 && electron ."

Answer (score 4):

Try this: paste this `BROWSER=none` in your project's `.env` file then save and re-run the project. Because maybe this a path related issue.

Comment: For clarity: You also remove `BROWSER=none` in `package.json` so the row says something like `"start": "react-scripts start".

Answer (score 0):

There is a very easy option on **Windows**:
**Win** + **Default Apps** + **Web Browsers** --> Change it as you wish. That's all.

Answer (score -1):

If you are running npm start then please check the following script in the package.json file.

```
"scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
```

},

And run

```
npm start
```

For me it worked